# Gray overlay and no dialog when clicking Image button in CKEditor

Tags: wysiwyg, media

Attempting to get CKEditor and Media to work together on a Drupal7 site. Things are mostly working great, but when I click the regular Image button (or double-click an image, or use the context menu to access image properties), I get only a gray overlay and no dialog window.

I'm using CKEditor 7.x-1.18 with the 4.10.0 FULL library locally installed (in libraries), as well as CKFinder 3.4.4 (also in libraries), all with Media 7.x-2.19 and the Media CKEditor 7.x-2.5 bridge module.

When I click the Image button, I get this error in console:

```
TypeError: Drupal.settings.picture is undefined[Learn More] plugin.js:152:15
init/<
http://example.com/sites/all/modules/picture/ckeditor/plugins/plugin.js:152:15
n
http://example.com/sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/ckeditor.js:10:222
CKEDITOR.event.prototype</<.fire</<
http://example.com/sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/ckeditor.js:12:42
CKEDITOR.dialog
http://example.com/sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/ckeditor.js:594:500
openDialog
http://example.com/sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/ckeditor.js:642:134
openDialog/<
http://example.com/sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/ckeditor.js:642:492
e
http://example.com/sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/ckeditor.js:258:175
y
http://example.com/sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/ckeditor.js:258:332
v
http://example.com/sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/ckeditor.js:258:412
A/e.$.onload/<
http://example.com/sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/ckeditor.js:259:327
```

I'm not Drupal-technical enough to understand this error entirely. But my intuition is that I don't have something configured correctly. (Installation instructions I have found are so ancient, I'm not even sure the module supports this version of CKEditor.)

Answer (score 0):

After discovering that the Image button works fine in the default "Advanced" text format, which I did not modify, and which doesn't have the Media button added, I started investigating differences.

Turns out that if I disable the Picture module in Editor Appearance > Plugins, things work.

I just don't know what I'm giving up by disabling this. I would like images to be responsive. :-(